# findViewById() cannot be resolved in my custom adapter

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i have just created a custom row and custom adapter for my little app. The problem at hand is when i try to use findViewById method in my custom adapter to get a reference to the TextView in my custom layout . Android studios put the letter in red and give me an error saying cannot resolve method findViewById(int).
Here is my code for the custom adapter:

```
package com.example.opeyemi.storytime;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
public class listViewBookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {


    public listViewBookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Book>books) {
        super(context,R.layout.row_layout,books);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflator=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View bookRow=inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        Book book=getItem(position);
        TextView bookNameLabel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bookNameLabel);
        return bookRow;

    }
}
```

Comment: `TextView bookNameLabel=(TextView)bookRow.findViewById(R.id.bookNameLabel);`. Also check out the view holder pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `bookRow` before `findViewById`

```
View bookRow=inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        Book book=getItem(position);
        TextView bookNameLabel=(TextView)bookRow.findViewById(R.id.bookNameLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bookRow.findViewById(R.id.bookNameLabel);
```

because you are inflating layout which returns layout view and it is assigned to bookRow as a reference variable.